# Handling Manifest missing in jar, with Exception?

Tags: java, exception, jar

I have to read information from Manifest fields in my program. All works good.
But I want to check the jar file first to make sure there is a Manifest. How can I do this? This is what I have so far:

```
try {
    InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(aJarLoc.toString());
    JarInputStream jInp = new JarInputStream(inp);
    Manifest manifest = jInp.getManifest(); //we need exception for missed manifest and for empty manifest!
    Attributes attr = manifest.getMainAttributes();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("something goes wrong");
}
```

Comment: A jar without a manifest and META-INF directory is not a jar, it's just a ziip. That will not change.

Comment: You can easily try what happens when you apply your program to a zip file, because the jar format is the same as zip. If you read the javadocs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html , you will see that you get a `null` if there is no Manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no manifest you will get a NullPointerException when calling manifest.getMainAttributes() which will be caught in your catch block.

You might want to control this yourself and throw a more meaningful exception:

```
if ( manifest == null)
{
    throw new Exception( "no manifest found in jar file " + aJarLoc);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Heri. This is what I  need, I'll do the same thing for fields in 'Attribute' and check it in Debug mode.